# vue3 blocks tree does not "reload" when changing the data

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I am looking for a organization chart plugin for vue 3 and I have found only this one

https://github.com/megafetis/vue3-blocks-tree

The issue that I have is when changing the ref `treeData` variable the chart is not loading  the new structure.

I want to dynamic load the chart. When fetch the data the chart to loads the new data and display it.

Here is the codesandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-gwen-o8vp9?file=/src/App.vue

When press the Add ... the `treeData` reference variable should load the new data and the chart to display it ... but it doesn't.

Any ideas ?

Should I reload the component on every fetch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use documented way make `treeData` reactive.

Replace `ref` to `reactive` for `treeDate` definition.
Change parts of `treeData` on `onAddData` instead replacing all object.

Full changed example:

```
import { reactive } from "vue";
import VueBlocksTree from "vue3-blocks-tree";
import "vue3-blocks-tree/dist/vue3-blocks-tree.css";

export default {
  name: "Diagram",
  components: { VueBlocksTree },
  setup() {
    let treeData = reactive({
      label: "root",
      children: [
        { label: "child 1" },
        { label: "child 2" },
        {
          label: "subparent 1",
          children: [
            { label: "subchild 1" },
            {
              label: "subchild 2",
              children: [{ label: "subchild 11" }, { label: "subchild 22" }],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    });

    // let treeData = ref({});

    const onAddData = () => {
      Object.assign(treeData, { label: "Test", children: [{ label: "Test 1" }, { label: "Test 2" }] });
    };

    return {
      treeData,
      onAddData,
    };
  },
};
```

UPD: Change code on `onAddData` by adding `Object.assign`.

Comment: I have allready tried that and saw that worked.....but I need the whole object to pass to treeData ... that comes from the server request

Comment: Try to use `Object.assign`:

```const onAddData = () => {
  Object.assign(treeData, { label: "Test", children: [{ label: "Test 1" }, { label: "Test 2" }] });
};```

Comment: it seems to work in sandbox. I will try to see if it works in the project. Thank you :)